# LibreOffice-Mono integration

Tags: libreoffice, mono

I had an old .NET Framework application running with Mono using OpenOffice and it worked very well.
Now I've just installed Ubuntu 11.10 Server and I discovered that it moved to LibreOffice, so I installed this suite on Windows, compiled using LibreOffice's CLI dlls and (on Windows) it works.
On Ubuntu I installed LibreOffice using `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`, but when I try to run my EXE I get a "TypeLoad Exception"; after an hard debug (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029620/mono-libreoffice-system-typeloadexception) I discovered that CLI libraries are missing.
I remember that with OpenOffice I had to install `cli-uno-bridge` package, but I'm able to find it anymore on Oneiric.
I've also tried to use `updatedb` and then `locate cli-`, but these libraries seem to miss on my system.
How can I install them? Basicly: I need to run a Mono application using LibreOffice...

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I found on this [web page](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/cli-mono/) deb packages I need (yes, I know, they are not supported... but just to try); so I downloaded them and tried to install with `dpkg -i *.deb`, but I canno install

- `dpkg -i cli-uno-bridge_3.4.3-3~bpo60+1_i386.deb`
  cli-uno-bridge depends on libuno-cli-cppuhelper1.0-cil
- `dpkg -i libuno-cli-cppuhelper1.0-cil_1.0.22.0+LibO3.4.3-3~bpo60+1_all.deb`
  libuno-cli-cppuhelper1.0-cil depends on cli-uno-bridge

So, one depends on the other... is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

if you're having an issue with a package disappearing, it may have been merged or renamed to another package.   To find out `http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/`  search for the old package name.  At the bottom there's a list files option.  In this case I used `libcli_uno.so`

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file  
sudo apt-file update  
apt-file libcli_uno.so
```

Yes, there is no package that provides it at the moment

If you're using those two debs, I would move them into a separate folder.  Then go there and `dpkg -i *`

Comment: I've already seen on one Ubuntu's web page that `cli-uno-bridge` and other libraries were deleted... So is there some hope for me? I have to wait that they distribute new package, right?

Comment: Take a look at my edited post please :)

Comment: see if that fixes it

Comment: I cannot install those two packages :(

Comment: LibreOffice stopped maintaining the Mono stuff and Debian/Ubuntu followed suit in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS/LibreOffice 3.5.X.